# Cant set value to select in Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in my component.when component initializing I want to set the value to the select field in my component, not as an option.value is getting from the server as observable after subscribing to it I want to display that values in the select field as default value

I tried

```
this.formName.get('controlName').setValue('valueFromServer')
```

and

```
this.formName.get('controlName').patchValue('valueFromServer')
```

and couple of stackoverflow solution as well but those are not worked for me.this is my stackblitz example.can any one tell me whats wrong here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izarqy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are setting the value to form control in right way as of my knowledge.

However as @Adrita pointed out `dropdown` will select the value  if `Options` **value attribute** contains it otherwise selection won't happen.

have look at this [**`StackBlitz`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxsrzu?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

**In Template :**

```
  this.tourPageForm.get('accomadation').setValue('valueFromServer'),
```

**In View:**

```
  <select  style="width:100px" formControlName="accomadation" class="form-control border">
         <option value="valueFromServer">1</option>
  </select>
```

**Edit :**

Actually *setValue* and *patchValue* are seems working here. We check that with below approach..

```
 this.tourPageForm.get('accomadation').setValue('valueFromServer');
 this.tourPageForm.get('mealType').setValue('Value recive from Server');
 console.log(this.tourPageForm.value)
```

When we try to console **`tourPageForm`**, will be able to observe below values..

```
accomadation: "valueFromServer"
mealType: "Value recive from Server"
transportation: ""
```

Which means `setValue` and `patchValue` are working fine but form `dropdown` is not able to select given value because they are not part current dropdown `Options`.

Comment: i will try this.do you know why this `patchValue()` and `setValue()` are not working?

Comment: Thanks! My list elements were missing the ID values that I expected them to have.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `<option>` values are integer, setting an integer that exists in option list will work. You have tried setting a string `'valueFromServer'`, which isn't present in the option list, therefore it isn't working

Try like this:

```
 this.tourPageForm.get('accomadation').setValue(1);
```

Note: If the values are fetched from server, make sure option list are fetched first, only after that setting values will work.

Comment: actually, values are not integer those are just a sample value. I getting a string from the server.btw I tried your solution it not worked for me

Comment: Ya, it's not really about the integer, it's just that it must be present in option values , and option values are loaded first. Are your option values are also getting fetched from server or it's static?

Comment: not getting form the server I'm going to use static array in the component. right now I want to get the value to select not to the option

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, Actually we need to match the value coming from the server with the current value set in `option` here is an example. otherwise it won't work.

### example.component.html

```
<select  formControlName="status">
          <option [value]="null">Choose...</option>
          <option value="pending">Pending</option> // only works if setValue('pending')
  </select>
```

### example.component.ts

```
this.exampleForm.get('status').setValue('pending');
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, after a lot of debugging our problem was that we didn't set properly the id.
The biggest issue was that it didn´t give a proper error in the console so we couldn´t find it and had to do a lot of debugging.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
<select
  formControlName="selectorControl"
  name="selector"
>
  <option
    *ngFor="let element of selectOptions; index as index"
    [ngValue]="element['id']"
  >
    {{element["description"]}}
  </option>
</select>
```

This *[ngValue]="element['id']"* was the issue, it was settled as *[ngValue]="element"*.
Once we changed it, everything worked like a charm.